# /rosout node is the one who publishes topics when I send rostopic pub?

Tags: ros, rosout, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys, I am new to ROS and starting to understand what happens in ROS so when I publish something like

```
$ rostopic pub -1 /turtle1/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -- '[2.0, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 1.8]'
```

Is it /rosout node responsible for publishing this topic or does Terminal have its own properties that can publish and subscribe to topics?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369540//rosout-node-is-the-one-who-publishes-topics-when-i-send-rostopic-pub-?/) by [Toshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/67052/toshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it /rosout node responsible for publishing this topic or does Terminal have its own properties that can publish and subscribe to topics?

No to both actually. `rostopic` is its own publisher.

[rosout](http://wiki.ros.org/rosout) (well, really `rosout_agg`) is basically `stdout`, but then for a complete ROS application (ie: all ROS nodes running).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0